# How to set Windows the default OS on dual boot system?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 (in a separate partition). Initially after booting, it shows me options to boot between Windows 7 and Ubuntu. But after updating Ubuntu, it now boots by default to Ubuntu. How do I make the default boot to Windows 7?

Comment: See this [dual boot - boot Windows by default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/162772#162772)