# Is it possible to remove and reinstall Ubuntu without affecting Windows?

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 on my system (dual boot),  Everything was working fine until graphical interface of Ubuntu crashes after updating it to 14.04.2 ([unity fails to start after booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610855/unity-fails-to-start-after-booting)). Now i want to reinstall Ubuntu but i am a little worry that  it might clean my windows data.
Is it possible to safely remove and reinstall Ubuntu without affecting Windows 8 files?

I will appreciate it if you explain what is the safest method.

Comment: I think this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/206721/how-to-remove-ubuntu-without-affecting-windows can get you with some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Yes. When installing, go into the advanced partition manager, selecting 'Something else' when installing. 
[image: Advanced partiton]
Then, when choosing root partition,
`/`
 **Make sure you choose the previous Ubuntu installation partition.** 
[image: partition]
Select it as 'ext4 journaling file system'
Make sure your partition labeled windows is marked as 'not used'

Comment: It was a little different (esp. the last part of it, where you need to check Formatting the selected partition) I think the difference can be ascribed to different release distribution.  Thanks a lot.