# How to change the default OS in grub?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I currently have a dual boot set up with Windows and Ubuntu 12.04.
Ubuntu is the default.

I'm looking for the commands to change and make Windows the default on Startup.

Comment: Possible duplicates are listed here: http://askubuntu.com/q/167459/25656