# I want to install windows 7 64 bit alongside ubuntu, but the windows installer won't install in the ntfs partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Good day, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on the entire partition on a laptop without an OS (Lenovo G480 i5-3230). Then, I decided to create an NTFS partition to install windows 7 64 bit (using a bootable USB) on it. However, when I want to boot with UEFI turned on in the BIOS, all I can boot is my Ubuntu. When I turn off the UEFI mode in the BIOS, I can boot from the USB but Windows 7 won't install on the NTFS partition. How do I install windows 7 alongside Ubuntu and make them both work?

gparted info:

```
/dev/sda1 fat32 /boot/efi 94.00 Mib 885.00KiB 93.14 MiB boot
/dev/sda2 ext4 / 361.10 GiB 37.89 GiB 323.21 GiB 
/dev/sda4 ntfs  100.67 GiB 3.00 GiB 97.66 GiB 
/dev/sda3 linux-swap  3.90 GiB --- --- 
unallocated  1.02 MiB --- ---
```

Comment: If with UEFI enabled your DVD doesn't show up in the boot selection screen (press F12 when you turn computer on), you'll have to prepare a USB installation media for Windows, eventually you can copy it on the same bootable USB that you are using now if you have 4GB remaining on it, they use different folders, eventually check for conflicts in the USB/efi/boot folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 slight "failures" for Windows. ( not failures for Linux ).

1.) windows-installer of Windows 7 only wants ntfs-partitions (you have boot-partition in FAT32 ? )

2.) windows-installer of Windows 7 only wants Windows 7 to bet on first parition (boot-partition) of your harddisk.

Later if you want it, that Windows should be by default in first line of boot-list in grub, you can read this here:

[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)