# Can the dual boot start be changed from grub to something else?

Tags: dual-boot

Could the dual boot be changed from the usual Grub menu to making a selection with the keyboard?

The idea is to select between, say, Windows and Ubuntu with a key instead of having Grub to appear.

For example: on PC start up, press <kbd>F1</kbd> to load Windows, or <kbd>F2</kbd> if I want to star Ubuntu.

Could this be done so nobody knows there are two different Operating Systems installed?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is an English only site. Please make the effort to have at least a rough translation of your question into English. [Spanish: Este sitio sólo está en inglés. Por favor hacé el intento de al menos darnos una traducción aproximada al inglés de tu pregunta.] Use, for example, [Prompt translator](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx?prmtlang=es).

Comment: He's asking if he can use a different key on bootup to select each operating system installed (like F1 for Windows, F2 for Ubuntu...) INSTEAD of GRUB, in order avoid one being able to see which operating systems are installed. I guess you'd have to use a different bootloader, or modify GRUB in order for it not to display the entries and for a specific key pressed down to load a specific entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily remove the timeout in `/etc/defaults/grub`. You change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` from 10 to 0. If you want something else than Ubuntu to be booted by default [you can follow this solution.](https://askubuntu.com/a/52990/83681) After changing you need to open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub`. (if you did it in this order you probably already have)

Then every time the machine starts, you can hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> the menu will show up and you can choose what to boot. If you don't it automatically boots the default OS without showing anything.