# How to edit GRUB Default Operating System?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-7

i'm using dual boot and i want to use windows 7 as the default operating system.So how can i change default OS of GRUB Boot loader?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use grub-set-default

```
$ sudo grub-set-default ENTRY
```

ENTRY is a number or a menu item title

or edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
sudo chmod +w /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
   change "0" in line: set default="0" to your choice
sudo chmod -w /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: It would be a better idea to edit /etc/default/grub and run 'update-grub' afterwards. /boot/grub/grub.cfg is not meant to be edited.

Comment: It would be good to note that the entry list can change so you may need to do this again later.  The other option would be to write out the entry rather than using the index number.

Example: GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sdc1)"

Answer (score 2):

How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?

This question was discussed previously and a detailed answer could be found here...

[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)