# How to change the default os

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Kubuntu 14.04. I want to change default OS from Kubuntu to windows 8.1

- I want information about Kubuntu only
- I searched and find out for Ubuntu not for Kubuntu

Comment: How does it matter what the OS is you want to change -from-?

Comment: Ubuntu and Kubuntu are the same; it's just that Kubuntu uses the KDE desktop environment whereas Ubuntu uses Unity. More than likely, though, you'll need to run commands in Konsole to change the default OS anyways.

Comment: There should be no real difference between Ubuntu and Kubuntu besides the desktop environment used (Unity vs. KDE). The default OS is selected by GRUB before the computer fully boots. Any information applicable to Ubuntu will work for Kubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GRUB (installed by default when you're installing Kubuntu alongside Windows), try using grub-customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401023/how-to-edit-grub-default-operating-system) and imagine that every time it says Ubuntu it's saying Kubuntu the only differences are the GUI, the boot process is identical.