# How can I make grub menu appearing after installing minimal Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, ubuntu-minimal

I have installed Ubuntu minimal 15.10 while having windows 10 installed in my laptop. During installation, I saw GRUB being installed, but after installation, GRUB menu simply doesn't appear.

I tried to press shift and space before the boot but nothing happened. I can't run live Ubuntu because it's a minimal image in my CD. Thanks a lot

EDIT: I can't boot Linux right now because the menu doesn't appear. The computer automatically boots Windows 10.

Comment: Please look at the solution in the below link..
http://askubuntu.com/questions/401023/how-to-edit-grub-default-operating-system

Comment: That doesn't help. I want the menu to appear because right now I can't even boot Ubuntu

Comment: Start your PC and hold down the Left Shift while it boots.  Is that working?

Comment: I tried it 2 different ways and no it didn't work. I'll try again though

Comment: Tried it two times now. It did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer is booting into windows instead of ubuntu because you don't have the partition GRUB is installed on marked as your first boot option. Go into your BIOS and you can easily change it... though the name of this drive probably won't show up as GRUB or Ubuntu, for me its just the name of my hard drive, if I want windows as my first boot option.. the drive is called Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: (I assume you know how to boot into your bios if you installed ubuntu already... but if you don't know  you'll have to start the pc and press a key specific to your mobo .. mine is DEL, could also be f2.)