# How to make GRUB menu for two different already installed OS in two different hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

The desktop has two different hard drive; 120GB SSD and 2TB HDD. I have Ubuntu 13.04 already installed in SSD and I partitioned HDD as 500GB, 750GB and 750GB. I used 750GB partitions to store files so that 120 will be left to Ubuntu only and left 500GB as unallocated space just in case.

Now Windows 8.1 has been installed to 500GB. SSD has the priority from the BIOS and unless it is changed from the boot menu, Windows is not able to boot.

What I want to do is to make/create a Grub menu so that the user of the desktop will have sometime to choose which to boot or if no choice is made, boot Ubuntu. I am not able to do a clean install to any OS.  Is there any possible way to make/create such a Grub menu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the grub boot records manually using this tutorial:

[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

Or use [grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) which is a gui based grub editor for Ubuntu.

In either case you need to have basic disk partition details and their notations. You can
use any disk management tools like Disk Utility which is pre-installed on Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!