# Changing Ubuntu and Windows 8 queue at dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I recently installed ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 and i'm new to ubuntu. I was wondering if i could change the queue from ubuntu to windows.

Actually,  when at the boot time count down is started for about 8 seconds and during this countdown you have to select ubuntu or windows 8 loader etc. to boot up if you don't select any of them it will automatically boot to ubuntu.

I want to know how can i change or reverse it from ubuntu to windows. So, if i don't select any of them it should boot automatically to windows instead of ubuntu because i use ubuntu less than windows.

Comment: here u go... Follow the steps 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit file */etc/default/grub*. To do so, open Gnome Terminal window and type:

*sudo gedit /etc/default/grub*

In the opened file, find line that looks like:

*GRUB_DEFAULT=0*

and change 0 to index of desired position in the list in GRUB menu displayed on boot. Note, that the menu list is counted from 0, not from 1. So if your Windows is, let's say on the 4th position, you must change 0 to 3:

*GRUB_DEFAULT=3*

After saving the file, you must update GRUB by running command:

*sudo update-grub*

Note, that instead of indexes, you can use operating system name, which can be found in the file */boot/grub/grub.cfg*. Scroll down to *menuentry* sections and you will find it with ease - it is something like *"Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1"* or similar.