# Grub Error - ^Y: comand not found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I was trying to change default boot option for my laptop(ubuntu and Windows). I can not update the grub which is the last step. When enter the command "sudo update-grub" i get this error "Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 1: ^Y: command not found".

I followed these instructions, 
[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I installed boot-repair tool and this is my URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11907417/

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/default/grub` has a stray `^Y` in it:

> ```
> =================== /etc/default/grub :
>
> ^Y
> # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
> # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
> # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
> #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
> ```

Just delete that line and you should be fine. You can use the following command to delete line 1 (since that's where the error is):

```
sed -i.bak 1d /etc/default/grub
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my current problem, but even though after updating grub I am not able to boot in windows as default OS.  The prompt still selects Ubuntu.