# How to dual boot Kubuntu without booting into GRUB when I turn on my computer?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, windows-10

What I want to happen is when I turn on my computer it boots into Windows 10 by default, and if I want to go into Kubuntu, I go into BIOS and choose to boot it. Is this possible without having Linux on a separate drive?

Comment: do you want to make Kubuntu by default or you want to run both window and kubuntu together

Comment: I want Windows to boot by default and be able to boot into Kubuntu by going into BIOS and selecting a boot option that will boot into Kubuntu.

Comment: you have to configure /boot/grub/grub.conf file . wait i am giving you solution

Answer (score 0):

go into terminal and  run command

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value lesser by default it wait for 10 sec so you can reduce it   if you don't want to see grub menu then do

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and restart system

it will not show grub menu if you want to start Kubuntu then you have to press key within 3 second otherwise default OS will start 
if you want to know how to change default OS then refer [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

Comment: This isn't quite what I want. What I want is to be able to not even go into GRUB and just boot Windows 10 by default and only go into GRUB and then Kubuntu when I select an option in the BIOS.

Comment: for that you have to reduce boot waiting time if you make it 5 sec or 3 sec like then it will start default OS without selecting BIOS . if you not select from BIOS still it start default OS but default waiting time is  more so you have to reduce it

Comment: @benthegameboy  you got solution or you want any other help. let me know if you face any problem