# Trying to change default OS but permissions won't allow changes to /etc/default/grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, permissions

I recently performed a reinstall of Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my hard drive. All of my files were salvaged, but I'm having some issues that I didn't have before with my root directory. I'm trying to change the default OS in the boot menu (I was able to choose Windows before the reinstall), but now I'm trying to go about it in the same way and I'm being blocked by permissions.

I tried following the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/52990/440489) so that I could hopefully use sudo to circumvent the permissions, but when I try and open /etc/default/grub with it, I end up opening a blank page instead of the actual file I'm trying to edit.

Comment: You misspelled `default` (`defualt`) in your title here: perhaps you did the same on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with `gksu` and `gedit`. Just execute `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.