# Cant access Ethernet and wifi on Dell laptop E7470

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless, additional-drivers

I have a new DELL Latitude 7470 with Ubuntu 14.04. I am not able to use WIFI or even Ethernet on the laptop but the internet using USB tethering works. I think it might be drivers issue.

The `lshw -C network` shows the following output

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e1100000-e1101fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   version: 21
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e1200000-e121ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: usb0
   serial: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.130 link=yes multicast=yes
```

The `lspci` command shows the following output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d14 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d48 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 525a (rev 01)
```

The command `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` shows no output at all and also gives no error.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the interfaces are configured with static IP?

Comment: How to check that ?

Comment: If you click on the network/wifi symbol on the upper right corner and then you go to "edit connections" you can configure the networks using a GUI. If you haven't ever changed the default configuration, it should be using DHCP and the problem could be different.

Comment: I had never changed the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, same computer, same OS. At the moment I am still looking into the matter, but it appears that Kernel version 3.19.0.68 is somehow responsible for the issue.

As a temporary solution at boot time press ESC when the Ubuntu logo is displayed, select "Advanced Options" and then select another version of the kernel (for example the .30 works perfectly)

As soon as I find a permanent solution I will post it here.

Comment: If you want to make the changes to the grub configuration so that your pc will automatically boot with the old Kernel you can do it following the instructions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader