# How to prevent Grub loader after updating to reset default OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates

Every time Grub updates (at least I think this is the trigger), it resets the default menu entry in `grub.cfg` from 3 (Windows) to 0 (Ubuntu).

I want Windows to be default one, without changing `grub.cfg` after every update.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, or, if no, at least revert changes with some scripting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grub defaults are defined in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
...
```

Open this file with your favourite editor (must be root or sudo), change `GRUB_DEFAULT=3`, save the file and run `sudo update-grub`.

For a more detailed (better) answer see this older post: [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)