# How to automatically boot into Windows instead of Ubuntu n times?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I need to do some necessary updates to my Windows system, but it is quite tedious to manually set the OS to Windows after each reboot at the grub menu.

Is there a way to set Windows to boot n times instead of Ubuntu so that I can leave my machine alone to do what it needs to do?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI it's as easy as giving priority to Windows manager in the UEFI boot order and change it back to Ubuntu when done. With BIOS/MBR perhaps the best way is to edit Grub in order to have Windows as default; edit back to Ubuntu when done. No, "n times" is NOT possible.

Comment: @MichaelBay UEFI, but I suppose I was trying to complicate things.  :) Changing boot order for the day would be fine.

Comment: This link can halp you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for grub to automatically reboot into Windows from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014467/is-there-a-way-for-grub-to-automatically-reboot-into-windows-from-windows)

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't solve your problem let me know and I'll retract the close vote. Thanks.